# UniqueEntity datetime Symfony4 : "The field is not mapped by Doctrine, so it cannot be validated for uniqueness."

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm trying to use UniqueEntity for datetime field. When I'm using this with string field or email, everything's ok. But with datetime: "The field "date_one" is not mapped by Doctrine, so it cannot be validated for uniqueness."

```
(...)
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\VisitRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("date_one")
 */

(...)

/**
* @ORM\Column(name="date_one", type="datetime", unique=true)
* [$dateOne description]
* @Assert\DateTime
* @var string A "m/d/Y H:i:s" formatted value
* @Assert\Range(
*      min = "now"
* )
*/
protected $dateOne;
```

An idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it's ok with this :

```
(...)
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\VisitRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"dateOne"},
 *     message="Cette date est déjà prise"
 * )
 */

(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `dateOne` instead of `date_one`, as the field for the `UniqueEntity`?

Comment: When I use dateOne : "An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.grouptype AS grouptype_2, t0.groupname AS groupname_3, t0.fullname AS fullname_4, (...*) FROM visit t0':

SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column t0.dateone does not exist
LINE 1: ...il AS email_8, t0.num_visitors AS num_visitors_9, t0.dateOne...
^
HINT: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "t0.date_one"."

Comment: My guess was that the `UniqueEntity ` looked at the model property not the column, I hadn't time to check it myself...

Looking at your other comment, it worked that was what i meant ;)